# C# - LockBits - Compare a image WITHIN other image

Tags: c#, image, compare

Sorry for bad English. I already searched on internet about what I am looking for, but never find EXACTLY what I need.

I have this code that compare two images and return true if both images are equal.

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Bitmap myBitmap1 = new Bitmap("Images\\img1.png");
    Bitmap myBitmap2 = new Bitmap("Images\\img2.png");

    bool equals = true;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, myBitmap1.Width, myBitmap1.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData1 = myBitmap1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, myBitmap1.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData bmpData2 = myBitmap2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, myBitmap2.PixelFormat);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptr1 = (byte*)bmpData1.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* ptr2 = (byte*)bmpData2.Scan0.ToPointer();
        int width = rect.Width * 3; // for 24bpp pixel data
        for (int y = 0; equals && y < rect.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                if (*ptr1 != *ptr2)
                {
                    equals = false;
                    break;
                }
                ptr1++;
                ptr2++;
            }
            ptr1 += bmpData1.Stride - width;
            ptr2 += bmpData2.Stride - width;
        }
    }
    myBitmap1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
    myBitmap2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(equals));
}
```

Everything works great.

But how can I make this code to return true if image 1 is WITHIN image 2?
I mean, I dont need to verify if image1 and image2 are equal, I need to verify if I can find image 1 WITHIN image 2!!

And more, if I find image 1 within image 2, how can I store in a variable the exact point coordinate (X, Y) of the place where it found image 1 within image 2?

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: For ever pixel in one image, you need to compare it against every potential pixel in the other, and also you will probably want to make sure you have locked to 32bpp

Comment: In short you dont have enough loops if you are looking at xy, however you could use 2 loops with just the raw array of each image

Comment: Also you could probably make use of p/invoke memcmp, You could also just iterate through until you find the first color in the first pixel and usep/invoke  memcmp to compare a whole scanline, you could also do this in parallel for speed

Comment: @Saruman, i am really new to C#. Can you make a piece of code of what you are sugestin?